# Add class to last div in lists using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have this list...

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <div class="class3">
            <span class="class4">test</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <div class="class3">
            <span class="class4">test</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <div class="class3">
            <span class="class4">test</span> <--- Add class5 here in addition to class4
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I add class2 in the correct spots? I need it to add to the last span every time even though the number of spans will change. I have something like this, but it doesn't account for the number of items in the list.

```
jQuery(".class4)").addclass("class5");
```

Is there anyway to do a "last" class4 scenario? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show that scenario please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
jQuery('.class4').last().addClass('class5');
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [last](http://api.jquery.com/last/):

```
jQuery('.class4').last().addClass('class5');
```

Comment: This form will generally be faster than the ones with `:last` due to sizzles right to left selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:last`

http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

```
$(".class4:last").addClass("class5");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the last selector of jQuery
http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

```
$(".class4:last").addClass("class5")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a stray closing parenthesis after `.class4` in your selector:

```
jQuery(".class4").addclass("class5");
```

This still does not work because `addClass` is case sensitive[1]:

```
jQuery(".class4").addClass("class5");
```

But to target only the last `.class4` you can use the `:last` pseudo-selector[2]...

```
jQuery(".class4:last").addClass("class5");
```

... or the `.last()` jQuery method[3]:

```
jQuery(".class4").last().addClass("class5");
```

---

[1] http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

[2] http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

[3] http://api.jquery.com/last/

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev What he pointed out was correct (`.addClass()` is indeed case sensitive) and thus was worthy of being a comment. It didn't attempt to answer the question before the edit, though, so it wasn't even an answer in the first place.